# Best image format for performance on itextpdf

Tags: android, image-processing, memory-leaks, itext

I have got some performance problems with iText. It takes about 20 seconds to put an image into the PDF. The thing is that I have time to make those images in any format, but I should be able to add those images to PDF very quickly.

The code is for image creation is:

```
androidsScreenElement.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
androidsScreenElement.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap cache = plot.getDrawingCache();
fos = new FileOutputStream("filepath.png", true);
cache.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

This code may run as long as it should to make optimal image for the PDF creator.

The PDF creator code is:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 10, 70, 70);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
Image image = Image.getInstance(APsFile.getAbsolutePath());
image.scalePercent(65);
image.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.add(image);
```

And this is a critical part, PDF code takes too long to execute. I am wondering what an optimal image format would be. Also I cannot do caching because my android device has too litle memory already so I have to keep all 5 images in the file for before it runs the PDF generation code.

Comment: JPEG is 4 times faster.

Comment: That is to be expected as JPEG is a format supported directly by PDF.

Comment: Do You think it may be better to save unformatted cache Bitmap somehow. Instead of even converting it to Jpeg an then read it from file and convert again?

Comment: I have not really done such benchmarks yet. ;)